# Parse XML tag attribute value into data frame in R

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I have a .xml file, looks like this:

```
<link dst="7456" id="1235">
 <wpt id="1" x="33442"/>
</link>
<link dst="4553" id="4572"/>
<link dst="6222" id="4084"/>
<link dst="3451" id="6884">
 <wpt id="2" x="33442"/>
</link>
<link dst="9374" id="7462"/>
 <wpt id="3" x="84733"/>
 <wpt id="4" x="49473"/>
</link>
<link dst="4310" id="9528"/>
```

Full file could be find here: 
[full file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvj89rhvildl5uy/s1101-1.xml?dl=0)
Basically the link without  tag is intermediate links. And one link with multiple  means those wpts fall on same link. So the output I want is a data frame like this:

```
wpt_id   link_id
  1       1235
mediate   4572
mediate   4084
  2       6884
  3       7462
  4       7462
mediate   9528
```

I want to use the XML package. Tried the getNodeSet function, convert it into list, but don't know how to continue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 1 link and 0 to many wpts, you could get a list of wpt and link ids from the link nodes and join.

```
nodes<- getNodeSet(doc, "//link")
link <- lapply(nodes, xmlGetAttr, "id")
wpt <- lapply(nodes, xpathSApply, "./wpt", xmlGetAttr, "id")
n <- sapply(wpt, length)
data.frame( wpt_id = unlist(wpt),  link_id= rep(unlist(link), n))

  wpt_id link_id
1      1    1235
2      2    6884
3      3    7462
4      4    7462
```

I had to remove the /> from the last link

```
doc <- xmlParse('<xml>
<link dst="7456" id="1235">
 <wpt id="1" x="33442"/>
</link>
<link dst="4553" id="4572"/>
<link dst="6222" id="4084"/>
<link dst="3451" id="6884">
 <wpt id="2" x="33442"/>
</link>
<link dst="9374" id="7462">  
 <wpt id="3" x="84733"/>
 <wpt id="4" x="49473"/>
</link></xml>')
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!@Chris

Comment: I have met another problem, no idea how to do this. Plz help guide if possible.

Comment: Nodes without a wpt tag are empty, so just replace them with `wpt[sapply(wpt, length)==0] <- "mediate"`  (before getting `n <-` above).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, just don't know how to implement...thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for it using `XML` library and `xpathSApply` function.

```
library(XML)
links <- xpathSApply(xmlInternalTreeParse(file.xml), "//link", saveXML)
getId <- function(link, type) {
       xpathSApply(xmlInternalTreeParse(link), 
                   paste("//", type, sep = ""), xmlGetAttr, "id")
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(links, function(link) {
              wptId = getId(link, "wpt") 
              linkId = getId(link, "link") 
              if(length(wptId) != 0) 
                  data.frame(wpt_id = wptId, link_id = linkId) 
              else 
                  data.frame() }))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works but Chris just answered a little earlier. @Psidon